# Talos - import talos - cannot import name 'tf_utils'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, talos

I installed talos and it broke my Keras/Tensorflow configuration.

If I run `import talos` OR `import keras`

I get:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'tf_utils'

When I installed talos it downgraded my Tensorflow to 1.14 and updated Keras to 2.3.
 At the same time I have a Tensorflow-GPU 1.8 (which was not changed), and is what I was running from my virtual environment before.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow 2.0 with Keras 2.3 solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `Tensorflow-gpu==1.8`. Replace it with `Tensorflow-gpu==1.14` and things will work.